# Can I remind a professor that I submitted a "good" essay in her class? (LOR request)

Tags: graduate-admissions, etiquette, recommendation-letter, professorship

I would like to ask my former professor for a reference, I'm not sure how to formulate it and am worried the professor won't remember me. I submitted a good essay in her class though (got an A).

Can I write:

> Dear Professor,
>
> I studied with you 2 years ago, I don't know if you
>   remember. In any case, I submitted a good essay in your class and
>   wanted to ask you for a letter of recommendation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better outline might be somehting like:

> Dear Professor Smith,
>
> I am planning to apply to Teleportation programme at the University of
>   Wonderland for my graduate studies. They require two reference
>   letters, and your area of interest is related to the programme I am
>   applying to.
>
> Would you please be kind enough to write a letter of recommendation?
>
> I have taken your course Introduction to Supernatural Incidents (ISI
>   101) in 2016 - 2017 Fall semester, and you have noted that one of my
>   assignments were outstanding.

Keep in mind that if you suspect that the professor wouldn't even remember you, it is better not to ask that professor for a letter of recommendation, because chances are they are going to write a mediocre letter.

**Why did I pick this outline**

Because first of all, the reason for you writing a mail should be explained at the first sentence. An avarage professor mailbox receives around 100 mails per day. Thus, they decide whether or not to read the full mail in a few seconds.

The **actual reason** for such mail is your application for graduate studies, and you give solid reasons for the letter of recommendation. Note that in your outline, the letter of recommendation is just *mentioned*. It seems like you wanted to remind the professor that you were his student, and handed in a good essay.

Another reason is, the punctiation and language. Although overly-formal emails are not good, using a proper language helps.

To sum up, the professor wants to know three things very clearly, and as soon as possible:

1. Why are you writing this mail?
2. What do you want from me?
3. Why would I grant your wish?

Comment: thanks a lot. I don't think he will remember me immediately from my name, but I think that if I remind him of the essay I wrote, he will probably remember. Do you think that's a bad strategy?

Comment: He probably had more dozens of good essays in past two years. But maybe it would be helpful if you got A from that course. It is a nice justification to write a LOR based on the semester grade.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also explain what makes your outline better? I would just like to understand why you structured it the way you did / what's your thinking behind it.

Comment: @J.Miller I have edited my answer to respond your comment.